# C# Are the variables inside the static methods initialized in the beginning or when the method is called first?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, static-methods

In C# 3.5 in a class I have a few static methods with some variables. Static methods are initialized first even if I do not initialize the class.

So are the variables inside the static methods also initialized in the beginning and not garbage collected ?

I want to know - will the memory be allocated for such method-variables even if I do not call the method or I call the method once and the method exits ? Or every time the method is called and it exits - the variables inside a method are garbage collected ?

Comment: I agree with Marc Gravell, as I am new to the site so can't vote for his post.

Comment: @Imran welcome to the site; just to note: we try to encourage people only to post *answers* as "answers"; I've converted your answer to a comment. You should gain the ability to add comments pretty quickly (there's a small rep limit, just to stop abuse)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Static methods are initialized first

no, static methods aren't "initialized" as such; they are (in standard implementations) JITted on first usage, but that is unrelated to memory allocations.

> So are the variables inside the static methods also initialized in the beginning and not garbage collected ?

method variables are **per call** (on the stack) - not globally; the stack space is assigned as you enter the method. If you have reference-type variables, they will go out of scope when the method exits (assuming those variables aren't "captured" into a delegate or lambda expression that lives longer that the method).

Only *objects* are garbage collected; not variables. Reference-type variables just *hold a reference* to the object.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I got the concept. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Static method variable are created when method is called and will go out of scope when method execution ends and they become ready for being garbage collected.

Comment: saying "disposed" here is very misleading, as that has a very specific meaning that **does not** apply here

Comment: Yes I changed the answer in effect I wanted to to say they become ready for be be garbage collected